# Unable to upload policy, The element 'ClaimType' has invalid child element, expected: 'InputValidationReference, PredicateValidationReference'

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

When I try to upload the following claim it fails:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="my-claim">
    <DisplayName>My Claim</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>some text</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
        <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="..." />
    </Restriction>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="blah" />
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="blah" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

With the following error:

> Unable to upload policy. Reason : Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORK_BUILDINGBLOCKS" of tenant "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com".
>
> Schema validation error found at line 172 col 10 in policy "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORK_BUILDINGBLOCKS" of tenant "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com": The element 'ClaimType' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06' has invalid child element 'DefaultPartnerClaimTypes' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'.
>
> List of possible elements expected: 'InputValidationReference, PredicateValidationReference' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'.

---

If I **move** `<DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>` **up** a little, the policy uploads.

```xml
<ClaimType Id="my-claim">
    <DisplayName>My Claim</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="blah" />
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="blah" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes> 
    <UserHelpText>some text</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
        <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="..." />
    </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

---

That doesn't seem "right" to me.  The order of children of `<ClaimType>` shouldn't matter, right?

Is that order specified in the [XSD file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd)?  (I heard I can configure VS Code to validate my XML against the XSD, I need to figure out how to do that...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [the "ClaimType" type](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/3b4898fec3bf0014b320beffa6eb52ad68eb6111/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd#L1169) requires the child elements to be appended in the declared sequence, as defined by [the XML schema](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd); otherwise it doesn't pass the schema validation.

This also applies to all other types that are defined by this XML schema.